# MySql Left Join with subselect

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, left-join

I have 2 tables (user and infos).
I need to select all user data and the related last inserted 'infotext' (insert_time)

table user

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | adress   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Name 1 | Adress 1 |
|  2 | Name 2 | Adress 2 |
|  3 | user 3 | adress 3 |
|  4 | user 4 | adress 4 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

table infos

```
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
| id | id_user | infotext | insert_time         |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | info 1   | 2016-11-24 14:03:23 |
|  2 |       1 | info 2.  | 2016-11-24 14:08:30 |
|  3 |       3 | text 3.  | 2016-11-24 14:08:46 |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT  a.*, b.infotext FROM    user a LEFT JOIN infos b
            ON a.id = b.id_user
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT      id_user, MAX(insert_time) newestInsert
            FROM        infos
            GROUP BY    id_user
        ) c ON  c.id_user = b.id_user AND
                c.newestInsert = b.insert_time
```

But the problem is it outputs the id not distinct:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | name   | adress   | infotext |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Name 1 | Adress 1 | info 1   |
|  1 | Name 1 | Adress 1 | info 2.  |
|  3 | user 3 | adress 3 | text 3.  |
|  2 | Name 2 | Adress 2 | NULL     |
|  4 | user 4 | adress 4 | NULL     |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

The final result I need is:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | name   | adress   | infotext |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Name 1 | Adress 1 | info 2.  |
|  3 | user 3 | adress 3 | text 3.  |
|  2 | Name 2 | Adress 2 | NULL     |
|  4 | user 4 | adress 4 | NULL     |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Add a GROUP BY, do max on infotext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the second condition in the `on` clause.  This method does it as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  u.*, i.infotext
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     infos i
     ON u.id = i.id_user and
        i.insert_time = (SELECT MAX(i2.insert_time)
                         FROM infos i2
                         WHERE i2.id_user = i.id_user
                        );
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is key...

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name   
     , u.adress   
     , i.infotext 
  FROM user u 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM infos x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT id_user
                   , MAX(insert_time) insert_time 
                FROM infos 
               GROUP 
                  BY id_user
            ) y 
           ON y.id_user = x.id_user 
          AND y.insert_time = x.insert_time
     ) i 
    ON i.id_user = u.id 
 ORDER 
    BY infotext IS NULL, infotext;
```